# Drag and Drop function is not working in selenium webdriver with nodejs (javascript) test automation framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automation, action

I'm using **selenium** webdriver + **nodejs** automation framework. Trying to drag and drop a slider using actions class but not working. Below is my code snippet and error:

Code :

```
let element: string = "//div[@class='rc-slider']/div[contains(@class,'rc-slider-handle-1')]";

const actions = driver.actions({ bridge: true });

actions.dragAndDrop(element, { x: 100, y: 0 }).build().perform();

TypeError: location.getId is not a function
      at ActionSequence.mouseMove 
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js`:188:7`)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try Below Code it solve your issue**

```
public static void draganddrop(WebDriver driver, String src_xpathExpression, String Des_xpathExpression ) {

    WebElement src = driver.findElement(By.xpath(src_xpathExpression));
    WebElement des = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Des_xpathExpression));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(src).moveToElement(des).release().build();

}
```

Comment: I'm looking for workaround in javascript, not in java